# Orientation issue in Better picker in android

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I use to show the better picker date dialog in button click event.

I have problem while changing the orientation.  now all I wanna do is to close this better picker dialog as below line

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
    {
        getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("better_date_picker").getParentFragment().getActivity().finish();
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    }
```

The problem is my app getting crashed while changing the orientation, as It cannot find better_date_picker fragment.
please some one help me..

Comment: add in manifest andorid:config changes

Comment: android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"  this is what I already have in my manifest.. Thanks for the quick reply.